# Parse query to get count of records by month and year using parse javascript sdk

Tags: javascript, date, parse-platform, sdk

I am trying to retrieve count of rows from parse object by month and year to show analytics by month. I am new to parse sdk and have no idea how to query based on month and year. Please help me in this.

Comment: Can you put the code to understand better your problem?

Answer (score 1):

monthStart/monthEnd/yearStart/yearEnd is Date

```
var m_query = new Parse.Quer("COLLECTION");
m_query.greaterThan('createdAt', monthStart);
m_query.lessThan('createdAt', monthEnd);
m_query.count().then(num=> console.log(num));

var y_query = new Parse.Quer("COLLECTION");
y_query.greaterThan('createdAt', yearStart);
y_query.lessThan('createdAt', yearEnd);
y_query.count().then(num=> console.log(num));
```